# Jquery .click for one second

Tags: jquery, time, click

how to make the function work only after click button for one second?

eg

```
$("#button").click(function(){
$(".panel").addClass('flip');
```

I want `'flip'` only if the button is pressed for 1 second. if you click on it for less than a second it does not `'flip'`

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button").mousedown(function(e){
    var self = this;
    clearTimeout(self.mouseUpTimer);
    self.mouseUpTimer = setTimeout(function(){
      $(self).bind('mouseup.delay', function(e){
        $(".panel").addClass('flip');
        $(self).unbind('mouseup.delay');
      });
    }, 1000);
  }).mouseup(function(e){
    clearTimeout(this.mouseUpTimer);
  });
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zSPhK/

Comment: thank you very much. Now, how do the reverse? pressing for more than 1 second, it does not 'flip', only if you press for less than 1 second

Comment: It should work for anything greater than or equal to a 1 second mousedown event.

Comment: Thanks, but not exactly what I need. This should not work in the "MouseDown" but the "MouseUp". Then, the event should occur after the MouseUp. when MouseUp, if pressed (mousedown) for 1 second (hold) it will 'flip'. when you MouseUp, if pressed (mousedown) for less than one second (click) does not 'flip'. suggest?

Comment: I edited the answer and provided an example. Please update your question to reflect your needs.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544948/click-and-hold-to-scroll-touchstart-touchmove-touchend

Comment: Dude, you answered correctly all I asked in this topic, so I'll leave it as is because it can help the needs of others. However, while experimenting, I discovered that not meet my needs. so I opened another topic which best explain all the settings that I need. If you can help me, I'll be grateful. Thank you.

Comment: Incidentally, this code is used for any longer than 1 second. As can use it to values ​​less than or equal to one second?